# How Can The Root Node Of A Horizontally Oriented PrimeFaces Tree Be Hidden?

Tags: primefaces

The question says it all. When the tree is presented vertically the root node is not displayed. Setting rendered to false does not do it.

Comment: no not possible in PrimeFaces 0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as usual, CSS comes to the rescue. A simple attempt with a browser developer tool on the [PrimeFaces showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/htree/basic.xhtml) (I don't use the horizontal tree myself), with putting a css `display:none` directly on the first html element with class of `ui-treenode` node html makes it disappear, including the first line.

[image]

But there are childnodes in there... Putting a `display:none` on the first html node with a class of `ui-tree-content` makes the content of the first node disappear and keep the line in tact and the rest of the tree still functions fine.

[image]

So we already effectivly know it can be done...

The only thing needed then is a 'full' selector. The folling hides ALL nodes, not what you want.

```
.ui-tree  .ui-treenode > .ui-treenode-content {
    display: none;
}
```

[image]

So the selector should be improved. Adding all intermediate elements to the **first** node is a solution

```
.ui-tree > table > tbody > tr > .ui-treenode > .ui-treenode-content {
    display: none;
}
```

[image]

(replacing the table, tbody and tr with a * would work too). But a more advanced solution where you actually select the first node with a class `.ui-tree-node`is

```
.ui-tree .ui-treenode:first-child > .ui-treenode-content {
    display: none;
}
```

And if you e.g. only want it on a specific horizontal tree, add a class to that tree (e.g. `no-root`) and use it in the selector as well

```
.no-root.ui-tree .ui-treenode:first-child > .ui-treenode-content {
    display: none;
}
```

What I effectively did here was (to try to) apply basic css knowledge and it provided a solution. Remember, client side it is (99.5% of the time) all html, css and javascript!!!

See also:
**See also:**

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Comment: I found that ".ui-tree .ui-treenode:first-child  { display: none; }" hides the root node and any leaf nodes which have no siblings. What worked for me is "td[data-nodetype="default"] { display: none; }" and setting the type of all of my nodes, other than the root node, to a custom value (ex. "visible")